# View for Entity Reference reverse, backwards forwards

Tags: 8, entities, views

The need is to present in a landing page a view of all pages that do reference to this landing page. So, this view will search in other content type, to find in a reference field that contain same id.

Landing page content type have several nodes children.

Page content type have a Entity reference field_back_parent for a node parent

Content types
Landing page (1) parent,
  Page (2) child,
  Page (3) child,

I would like to this using UI in admin. So, no entityQuery in this opportunity.

Comment: You can also use a module instead of (or instead of only) core views: https://www.drupal.org/project/reverse_entity_reference > Reverse Entity Reference adds a computed reverse reference field to all referenced entities.

Comment: Nice comprehensive answer below  from Carlos (I haven't tried it myself yet though). What I have tried and found to work is: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/298084/1082 (albeit a programmatic solution, but if one is already doing coding for their project, then this other answer is simple solution that I have tried).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- No additional module need to be installed.
- No coding needed. Just site building for Drupal 8.
- First we need to check if our content types are ready.

Landing page content type, don't need any change.
Page content type need a field of type **Entity reference**.

- **Add field** -> Add a new field = Reference Content

Then in Edit tab chose your kind of content type (parent)

[image]

After Save you will get...

[image]

Now go to admin/structure/views and + **Add view**

[image]

In this case we are going to check the option to **create a block**

[image]

In ADVANCED
[image]

**Add Relationship** for our field_back_parent in Page content type. *This important to connect the two content types.*

[image]

You need to tick **Require this relationship**.

[image]

In ADVANCED
[image]

Then **Add Contextual** filter for our current content type Landing Page. *In this way, we will get our actual node id to be used in the view. So, now we can find only the pages that have same node id in field_back_parent.*

So find by ID (Content)

[image]

Select the relationship name.

Check **Provide default value** -> **Content ID from URL**

[image]

Then you will get something like this:

[image]

In Relationship you must to have the word **Content** in the rightside

This is the result of our settings
[image]

If you click in **Update preview** you will corroborate that it doesn't display anything.

You must to add the node id from parent. In our case is the node 2 from Landing page. 
[image]

Other way for reference https://mushtaqtahir.com/blog/4/drupal-8-reverse-entity-reference-in-view

I hope that this info help you.