# Reverse entity reference lookup

Tags: entities, 9

I have a data structure where content type `research` has an entity reference field `scientists`.

The content type `scientists` does not have any `research` reference entity field though.

I can get all `scientists` that a particular `research` has through `research`.

But is there a way to get all `research`es one particular `scientist` has? When content types were created I wasn't involved, so I'm trying to see my options whether I can somehow click a checkbox to make this applicable.

When I tried to set up a field with type of `entity reference` and pointed it to research for scientists, they were empty.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you had a look at [Reverse Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/reverse_entity_reference), yet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [View for Entity Reference reverse, backwards forwards](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/255447/view-for-entity-reference-reverse-backwards-forwards)

Comment: @leymannx thanks again for your help. I'm using Drupal 9 actually, but the second link might be helpful. I don't need this in a view but in a preprocess function, so I'm wondering whether this will create the referenced entities when I go along.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to get all researches one particular scientist has?

Yes, search for the scientist target id:

```
$nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadByProperties([
  'type' => 'research',
  'field_scientists' => $scientist_id,
]);
```

Comment: +1 upvote. This also works in Drupal 9, 9.3.x - from personal experience - thank you!

Comment: need a similar soluton but where Entity Reference UUID is used: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/310697/programmatically-get-child-nodes-referencing-parent-by-entity-reference-uuid-us please.